# How can I achieve similar lights for this 3D object?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d

The left one is my turn on recreating the image seen on the right. I've found quite similar aluminum/metal material and played with the bevel to make it as similar as I could, but I can't replicate the light source.

As seen on the right, the top and bottom parts should be almost completely lit (white) and the sides should have more shadows.
I tried playing with the light sources but really couldn't do anything similar to it. The one that I'm using right now is a spot light (disabled the infinite light). Maybe the issue is in the bevel as well?

I'd be more than happy to assist the project file to someone who understands this and think could fix it for me, I'd be very grateful
[image]

Comment: Once you created proper bevel then if i would at your place i would go with layers blending instead of changing lights ( means keep infinite light; create new layers and make it while and glowing and for shadows create overlaying gradients ) but since you want to create it only in 3d then i'm not sure how to adjust parameters xD

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the light parameters? Light position? What exactly are the 3D settings for the layer?

Comment: It's not a 3D model, it's a 2D composition which contains also images of real or rendered 3D parts. For example the hexagon pattern is an inserted  flat 2D image- its viewing angle is constant. The problematic white edges of the frame can be , too. There are pieces of 3D frames which contain round aluminium bars There's also a glass plate which suggests that one of the material sources is an  image of a window. - a real one or a rendered 3d model. It's impossible to be sure. The colors are reduced to greyshades and red.

Answer (score 0):

right click object, add bevel emboss, adjust it to achieve what u want.
then add outer glow for the effects. You can add gradient for same color.

Comment: Hi and welcome to GDSE. Your answer is very short. Could you add some screenshots and a more thorough explanation? The OP has already added bevel, so I don't really understand what you mean.